# Angular - table sorting not working for nested objects

Tags: javascript, json, angular, sorting, angular-material

I have a angular table but the date is not sorting correctly. The rest of the columns sort perfectly fine besides the date. I think its because the date is a nested object, I tried using the matSortChange() but nothing works.

I have created a demo here:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7ycna-tv7nrs?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts)

```
 const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
     {position: 1,
       name: 'A', 
       weight: 1.5079, 
       timeModel: {CreatedTime: "2020-04-30T15:38:11.186Z", LastModified: "2020-06-08T15:38:11.186Z"}
      },
       {position: 2,
       name: 'B', 
       weight: 1.4079, 
       timeModel: {CreatedTime: "2021-03-30T15:38:11.186Z", LastModified: "2020-06-10T15:38:11.186Z"}
      },
       {position: 3,
       name: 'C', 
       weight: 1.3079, 
       timeModel: {CreatedTime: "2020-01-30T15:38:11.186Z", LastModified: "2020-03-30T15:38:11.186Z"}
      },
    ];
```

I did try to add a custom sort function to try to sort the dates but its not working correctly.

```
   public changeSort(event: Event) {

     if (event.active === 'date') {   
       this.dataSource.filteredData = this.dataSource.filteredData.sort(function(a, b) {
      return new Date(a.timeModel.CreatedTime).getTime() - new Date(b.timeModel.CreatedTime).getTime();
    });
    }

  }
```

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" (matSortChange)="changeSort($event)" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.timeModel.CreatedTime}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

}
```

Comment: I bet it's sorting as a string. Convert date to Unix time directly in your data ex: { CreatedTime: 1567562058 }. When you display data on screen convert Unix time to Date() object and then format the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is because of it is an object. `matColumnDef="weight"` describes the property to be taken into the sorting function. So from this object:

```
{
  position: 1,
  name: 'A', 
  weight: 1.5079, 
  timeModel: {CreatedTime: "2020-04-30T15:38:11.186Z", LastModified: "2020-06-08T15:38:11.186Z"}
}
```

`weight` is taken. But `matColumnDef="date"` results in just an `undefined` - there is no property `date` in your objects.

So if possible, change the dataSource objects and provide only the date it needs (as it seems you only use `CreatedTime` anyways in your table).

You can also overwrite `sortingDataAccessor` [function of a MatDatSource](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts#L118), which originally looks like this atm:

```
sortingDataAccessor: ((data: T, sortHeaderId: string) => string|number) =
    (data: T, sortHeaderId: string): string|number => {
  const value = (data as {[key: string]: any})[sortHeaderId];

  if (_isNumberValue(value)) {
    const numberValue = Number(value);
    return numberValue < MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ? numberValue : value;
  }

  return value;
}
```

You need to add a condition to look if the current `sortHeaderId` value is a `'date'`. Then just tell it how to get the needed value of the object to be used in a sorting function:

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data, sortHeaderId) => {
  const value = (data as {[key: string]: any})[sortHeaderId];
  
  const MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991;

  if (_isNumberValue(value)) {
    const numberValue = Number(value);    
    return numberValue < MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ? numberValue : value;
  }

  if (sortHeaderId === 'date') {
    return new Date(data.timeModel.CreatedTime)
  }

  return value;
}
```

p.s. you need to import `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and `_isNumberValue` from Angular if want to preserve that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I can detect some issues in your code:

1. All your dates are the same, so no sorting will effect it.
2. You got inside the function `changeSort` a if statement `if(event.direction === "desc")`, Try to change it to `if(event.active === "date")`, the other sorts are working fine and you want to exclude this condition only to date sort.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the dates in the demo and updated the changeSort but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Angular does not know the correct way to property that should be sorted. So we can show it to Angular by using custom sorting data accessor:

```
public changeSort(event: Event) {
    console.log(event)
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
        switch (property) {
            case 'date': return item.timeModel.CreatedTime;
            default: return item[property];
        }
    };
}
```

[A complete stackblitz example example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7ycna-yviajh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Store unix timestamp as data and format it when you display on screen. This way you don't need to create the sort function.

Here is a working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7ycna-wdvvnw

Answer (score 0):

@StepUp's solution worked for me, however, I was getting an error.
I suppressed the error with `@ts-ignore`.
The error could have been specific to my situation.

These errors were reported:

> Type '(cart: Cart1, sortHeaderId: string) => string | number | Product | undefined' is not assignable to type '(data: Cart1, sortHeaderId: string) => string | number'.

> Type 'string | number | Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.`

Comment: Formatting of the error could be improved